# Como esconder as mensagens de erros padrões do navegador?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Gostaria que aparecesse no console, apenas a mensagem colocada no reject e ocultasse aquele erro de GET padrão do browser.

```
    function loadScript(src) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let script = document.createElement('script')
            script.src = src
            script.onload = resolve(script)
            script.onerror = reject(console.log(new Error('Ocorreu algum erro.')))
            document.head.append(script)
        })
    }
    loadScript('msf.js')
```

O erro:

```
Error: Ocorreu algum erro.
    at promise_version.html:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at loadScript (promise_version.html:14)
    at promise_version.html:23

GET file:///home/art/Art/promise_assync_await/msf.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
(anonymous) @ promise_version.html:19
loadScript @ promise_version.html:14
(anonymous) @ promise_version.html:23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` é do próprio navegador, não sendo possível tratá-lo com Javascript.

Ele é definido no Chromium/Chrome em `net_error_list.h`, [na linha 44](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:net/base/net_error_list.h;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=44):

```
// The file or directory cannot be found.
NET_ERROR(FILE_NOT_FOUND, -6)
```

Referências:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127436/how-to-catch-chrome-error-neterr-file-not-found-in-xmlhttprequest/48182975.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035466/check-if-file-exists-but-prevent-404-error-in-console-from-showing-up

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/280660)

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque @LuizAugusto! Melhorei minha resposta :)